# Be notified of a click on Taskbar Icon

Tags: icons, taskbar, autohotkey

Looking for a solution to a hidden window - either a windows event that occurs when the TaskBar Icon is clicked.
or alternatively, a way to remove the TaskBar Icon. The Tray Icon is easily hidden - that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample script on the AutoHotkey's Website called [Minimize Window to Tray](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/MinimizeToTrayMenu.htm)

The script itself uses the hotkey `Win+H` to hide the active window. `Win+U` then shows the last hidden window. If this is not the functionality you are going for, I'm sure you can take a look at the script and pick out what you need. Hope this helps you out.

Comment: I've a possible answer to detecting a Click on the TaskBar Icon - but I'm concerned it will differ for each version of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I've a possible answer to detecting a Click on the TaskBar Icon - but I'm concerned it will differ for each version of Windows. Using OnMessage(Wm_Activate := 0x06, "testmessage") - then MouseGetPos to get the Window name, I can eliminate all but 'MSTaskListWClass1' the name of the Icon I want. But I suspect that the name is only valid for Win7.

Comment: If you find a method for each OS you can always use the `A_OSVersion` variable. You can then deal with each accordingly.